# PHP tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

Tags: php, codeigniter, shell, exec, tput

I'm having the following error when using the [`exec()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

```
string(25) "/etc/init.d/mast list-log" 
array(1) { [0]=> string(44) "tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified" } 
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

My command is `/etc/init.d/mast list-log` and was working prior to reboot. I can't see what the difference.

### Source code

```php
public static function execute($_ = null, $debug=true) {
    $_ = $debug ? $_." 2>&1"  : $_;
    exec("$_ | aha --word-wrap --no-header", $output, $exitCode);
    return $output;
}
```

### Question

Do you have suggestion on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shell you can set an environment variable that has the life cycle of the following command as follow:

```
TERM=screen-256color ls -l --color=always
```

Where `TERM=screen-256color` is the environment variable and `ls -l --color=always` the command.

### Solution

Here is my modified code, I simply prepend `TERM=screen-256color` to my command:

```php
public static function execute($_ = null, $debug=true) {
    $_ = $debug ? $_." 2>&1"  : $_;
    exec("TERM=screen-256color $_ | aha --word-wrap --no-header", $output, $exitCode);
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, i have not your params : --word-wrap --no-header
$ aha -?
Ansi Html Adapter Version 0.4.4
aha takes SGR-colored Input and prints W3C conform HTML-Code
use: aha <options> [-f file]
     aha (--help|-h|-?)
options: --black,     -b: Black Background
    --pink,      -p: Pink Background
    --iso X,   -i X: Uses ISO 8859-X instead of utf-8. X
    --title X, -t X: Gives the html output the title "X" instead of "stdin" or the filename
    --line-fix,  -l: Uses a fix for inputs using control sequences to change the cursor position like htop. It's a hot fix, it may not work ...

Comment: Indeed, the `--word-wrap` was introduced in `0.4.5` (currently Ubuntu 12.04 use `0.4.4`) https://github.com/theZiz/aha/blob/master/CHANGELOG